# Looking for a faster way to compute conditioned reverse cumulative sums of large time series in R

Tags: r, dplyr, time-series, data.table, large-data

```
library(dplyr)
```

I have been studying R for a few months. I have been using Covid-19 data from the NYTimes ([NY Times Covid Data on Github](https://github.com/nytimes/covid-19-data))
as a test data set for learning about statistical programming.

From their Github repository, you can get the case data for the US as a whole, by state, or by county. Whichever one you are looking at, there is a cumulative total for the number of known cases and the number of deaths for each location and each date. A location doesn't show up in the data set until there is at least one case or death, and then once there it gets updated every day in perpetuity.

My goal is to come up with a way to do calculations for new cases since yesterday, new cases since last week, etc and add these calculations as new columns to my dataframe. I have found a strategy that works with smaller sets of data but gets pretty slow when dealing with nationwide data at the county level.

I will generate some random data to use as an example.

```
set.seed(123)

data <- data.frame(rep(seq(as.Date("2020-01-01"), as.Date("2020-04-30"), 1), 3))

names(data)[1] <- "date"

data$city[1:121] <- "Boston"
data$city[122:242] <- "NYC"
data$city[243:363] <- "Chicago"

data$newcases[1:121] <- round(runif(121, 10, 15))
data$newcases[122:242] <- round(runif(121, 15, 20))
data$newcases[243:363] <- sample(data$newcases[1:242], 121, replace = TRUE)

data <- data %>%  group_by(city) %>% mutate(totalcases = cumsum(newcases))


NYTIMES <- as.data.frame(data) %>% select(date, city, totalcases)

slice_sample(NYTIMES, n = 5)
```

```
        date    city totalcases
1 2020-01-09     NYC        152
2 2020-02-13     NYC        759
3 2020-03-10     NYC       1221
4 2020-03-16  Boston        950
5 2020-01-27 Chicago        412
```

So first I tried to reverse engineer the cumulative sum. I have not been able to successfully produce what I want.

```
NYTIMES <- NYTIMES %>%  group_by(city) %>% mutate(newcases = rev(cumsum(rev(totalcases))))

slice_sample(NYTIMES, n = 5)
```

```
# A tibble: 15 x 4
# Groups:   city [3]
   date       city    totalcases newcases
   <date>     <chr>        <dbl>    <dbl>
 1 2020-02-11 Boston         534    81524
 2 2020-03-01 Boston         763    69365
 3 2020-03-10 Boston         876    62066
 4 2020-04-15 Boston        1324    22739
 5 2020-04-27 Boston        1480     5996
 6 2020-02-07 Chicago        570    99599
 7 2020-04-21 Chicago       1690    17604
 8 2020-03-04 Chicago        934    80234
 9 2020-03-20 Chicago       1196    63351
10 2020-04-08 Chicago       1483    38157
11 2020-02-05 NYC            623   117708
12 2020-03-31 NYC           1588    57384
13 2020-04-29 NYC           2096     4210
14 2020-02-04 NYC            605   118313
15 2020-03-27 NYC           1523    63573
```

And I needed more flexibility than just figuring out the daily new cases anyway. A lot of the epidemiology models are based on comparing the known cases or deaths today to the known cases or deaths a week ago, or ten days ago, or three weeks ago, or whatever.

I built some for loops that worked okay, but the code was clunky and error-prone. And so I came up with this strategy using sapply with the sum function, bracket sub-setting, and binary relational operators. Coming from Excel world, this is basically an approximation of SUMIFS.

```
NYTIMES <- as.data.frame(data) %>% select(date, city, totalcases)

NYTIMES$a_day_ago <- sapply(seq_len(nrow(NYTIMES)), function(x) with(NYTIMES, sum(totalcases[date == (date[x] - 1) & city == city[x]])))

NYTIMES$new_cases <- with(NYTIMES, totalcases - a_day_ago)

n <- 12  #arbitrary number of days ago

NYTIMES$n_days_ago <- sapply(seq_len(nrow(NYTIMES)), function(x) with(NYTIMES, sum(totalcases[date == (date[x] - n) & city == city[x]])))

NYTIMES$active_cases <- with(NYTIMES, totalcases - n_days_ago)
                             
                             slice_sample(NYTIMES, n = 5)
```

```
        date    city totalcases a_day_ago new_cases n_days_ago active_cases
1 2020-03-21 Chicago       1214      1196        18       1014          200
2 2020-02-17  Boston        603       591        12        463          140
3 2020-04-20  Boston       1390      1375        15       1233          157
4 2020-02-06 Chicago        553       535        18        380          173
5 2020-03-15 Chicago       1116      1099        17        916          200
```

This works great and I can do all kinds of calculations playing off of this theme. New cases per day, new cases per week, per month. I can calculate a proxy for known active cases by taking the difference between the known cases today and the known cases from n days ago. Subtract the deaths from that and you have a good proxy for known recovered cases in a given area. Substitute the sum function for mean and you can do all kinds of rolling averages. Add some population data and you do it all on a per capita basis. And the subsetting is really powerful for looking at a particular region or metropolitan area or for comparing different locations based on demographic/mobility variables from other data sets. So I am mostly pretty happy with my progress, especially at the national and state levels.

However, when you start getting down to the county level it gets pretty slow as the datasets get pretty huge. Did you know there are 254 counties in Texas alone? And a lot of times the daily updates revise past numbers. Obviously, I can just schedule it to run over night or split the data up into smaller chunks, etc. But I'm interested mostly just to understand the mechanics of wrangling huge time series datasets efficiently.

So TLDR; is there a computationally faster method to do these calculations in a dataset with millions of rows?

And as secondary questions, people often mention data.table for very large datasets, would this be a good application for that package and what would the syntax look like? I haven't figured out how to do it without relying on the same sapply trick and then it's probably not any faster. Or are there time-series packages for R that do this kind of thing well already whose code I could examine for pointers?

Thank you

If it matters, I'm running RStudio 4.0.2 on Windows10. And I do most of my wrangling with base R and dplyr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend that you take a look at the `lag`/`lead` functions in dplyr. They are well suited to this application. These functions get values from the previous or next record in a dataset (under a specific order).

```r
df = data %>%
  group_by(city) %>%
  mutate(prev_totalcases = lag(totalcases, order_by = date),
         daily_cases = totalcases - prev_totalcases)
```

The above code creates a new column `prev_totalcases` that is the value of `totalcases` for the city on the previous date. It then calculates daily cases as the change between the current and previous total cases.

For working with dates I recommend you investigate the lubridate package. This has a variety of useful features such as turning text into dates, extracting the year, month, and day from dates, and combining them back together into dates.

Comment: That's perfect. That lag/lead function is exactly what I was looking for. Total elapsed time for my method on 500,000 rows of the database = 3752.87 seconds. Just tried it the same computation with the lag function = 0.37 seconds. And it works well with all of my "n days ago" models. Thank you.